# Firing 'click' event on input submit without ID or name?

Tags: c#, html, .net

I am trying to auto-fill a form on a webpage using .NET's web browser int he C# language. I need to fire the submit button but it doesn't have a name or ID, all it has is a type and value.

The type is equal to "submit" and the value is equal to "Sign In"

Heres how I did it for Sign Up:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").InnerText = email;
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = password;
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")["register"].InvokeMember("click");
```

But this time, the submit button doesn't have a name, can someone guide me in the right direction to getting an element by its type or even better, value?

HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="email">Email or Username</label> <span class="required">*</span> <input class="email" id="email" name="email" size="32" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Password</label> <span class="required">*</span> <input id="password" name="password" size="16" type="password">
        <p class="tip"><a href="/signin/reset" id="reset_password_link">I don't know my password</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input id="persistent_hidden" name="persistent" type="hidden" value="f"> <input checked="checked" id="persistent" name="persistent" type="checkbox" value="t"> <label for="persistent">Keep me logged in</label>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
        <input id="redirect_path" name="redirect_path" type="hidden"> <input type="submit" value="Sign In"> or <a class="cancel" href="/">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please update your HTML snippet to include the entire `<form>` element.

Comment: I've updated my question to the entire form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try :**

```
foreach(HtmlElement elem in webBrowser.Document.getElementByTagName("input")) {
    if (elem.GetAttribute("value") == "Sign In") {
        elem.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
 }
```